# jQuery trigger not behaving as expected when targeting an element directly

Tags: jquery, triggers

Given this HTML

```
<div id="section-name">
    <div id="item">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And this jquery

```
$("#section-name div").click(function(){
    // do stuff
});
$("#item").trigger("click");
```

I would expect whatever i have in // do stuff to execute.  However, it doesn't.  If I click directly on the element I get the expected behavior.

Nothing I've found in the documentation for trigger helps me understand if this is expected behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: Your selector is wrong; should be $('#section-name div')

Comment: Sorry, just fixed the error in the example.  The actual code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my mistake.  It seems that there were some duplicate IDs in the HTML.  Note to self... always validate before posting!

Maybe this will help someone else with a similar lack of discipline.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery Selector is wrong; it should be:

```
$("#section-name div").click(function(){
    // do stuff
});
$("#item").trigger("click");
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT: Thank you to vzwick for this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6XTXs/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any `#section` id in your HTML, you have `#section-name`. For `// do stuff` to execute, change your HTML to this:

```
<div id="section">
    <div id="item">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Or with HTML5, do the following:

```
<section>
    <div id="item">
    ...
    </div>
</section>
```

And then change your event listener to the following (notice the lack of the `#`):

```
$("section div").click(function(){
    // do stuff
});
```